# Homogeneous D.E

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

show that $ x\frac{dy}{dx} = y + \frac{x}{lny-lnx} $ is a homogeneous D.E.

Find the general solution in the form $ye^{y/x} = f(x) $

The answer given is $ye^{y/x} = Ax^2 $ but I am getting $ (\frac{y}{x})^{y/x} = Axe^{y/x} $

Is the given answer correct?

Comment: Try putting the given answer back into the ode? if that checks out then please give more details to your solution to see if and where you are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the given answer $\quad ye^{y/x} = Ax^2 \quad\to\quad \ln(y)+\frac{y}{x}=\ln(A)+2\ln(x) \quad$ and differentiate it :
$$\frac{dy}{y}+\frac{dy}{x}-\frac{ydx}{x^2}=2\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\left( \frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{x}\right)dy=\left(\frac{2}{x}+\frac{y}{x^2} \right)dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{2}{x}+\frac{y}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{y}{x}\left(\frac{2x+y}{x+y}\right)$$
$$x\frac{dy}{dx}= y\left(\frac{2x+y}{x+y}\right)=y\left(1+\frac{x}{x+y}\right)$$
$$x\frac{dy}{dx}= y+\frac{x}{\frac{x}{y}+1}\tag 2$$
Compared to the given ODE 
$$x\frac{dy}{dx}= y+\frac{x}{\ln(y)-\ln(x)}\tag 1$$
we see that $\quad ye^{y/x} = Ax^2\quad$ should be the solution of $(1)$ if $\quad \frac{x}{y}+1=\ln(y)-\ln(x)\quad$

Except for particular values of $x$ and $y$, this isn't the case in general.

So, in general $\quad ye^{y/x} = Ax^2\quad$ isn't solution of $(1)$.

The general solution of $(1)$ is $ (\frac{y}{x})^{y/x} = Axe^{y/x} $

Probably there is a typo or a mistake in the wording of the problem. May be the question isn't to find the general solution of $(1)$, but only to find a particular solution on a specified form.